# Understanding the set() function

Tags: python, set

In python, `set()` is an unordered collection with no duplicate elements. However, I am not able to understand how it generates the output.

For example, consider the following:

```
>>> x = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> set(x)
set([1, 2, 3])

>>> y = [1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
>>> set(y)
set([8, 1, 6])

>>> z = [1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]
>>> set(z)
set([1, 6, 7])
```

Shouldn't the output of `set(y)` be: `set([1, 6, 8])`? I tried the above two in Python 2.6.

Comment: You said yourself that a set is an *unordered collection*...

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Sets are unordered, as you say. Even though one way to implement sets is using a tree, they can also be implemented using a hash table (meaning getting the keys in sorted order may not be that trivial).

If you'd like to sort them, you can simply perform:

```
sorted(set(y))
```

which will produce a sorted list containing the set's elements. (Not a set. Again, sets are unordered.)

Otherwise, the only thing guaranteed by `set` is that it makes the elements unique (nothing will be there more than once).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note: Sets in general can be implemented using trees. `set` in Python cannot (meaningfully), as it's guarantees that they require the items to be hashable and don't require them to be comparable.

Comment: @delnan -- And just to be abundantly clear, by *comparable* you mean *rich comparisons* (`<`, `>`).  In order for an object to be "hashable" it must implement `__eq__`.

Comment: @mgilson: Tangentially, in 2.x if you override `__eq__` and need to use instances in a `set` or as `dict` keys, then you should also override `__hash__` such that equal objects hash the same. Or define `__hash__ = None` to make it unhashable. In 3.x, if you override `__eq__` you are required to override `__hash__` if you want the type to be hashable.

Comment: @eryksun -- Yes.  I suppose I should have said that it *also* must implement `__eq__` (in addition to `__hash__`).

Comment: @mgilson: For 2.x I should have said 'implement' `__eq__`, not 'override' it, since only 3.x has default rich comparison methods. However, there is a default `object.__hash__` in 2.x. It's OK to override this without implementing `__eq__`, just not vice versa.

Answer (score 14):

As an unordered collection type, `set([8, 1, 6])` is equivalent to `set([1, 6, 8])`.

While it might be nicer to display the set contents in sorted order, that would make the `repr()` call more expensive.

Internally, the `set` type is implemented using a hash table: a hash function is used to separate items into a number of buckets to reduce the number of equality operations needed to check if an item is part of the set.

To produce the `repr()` output it just outputs the items from each bucket in turn, which is unlikely to be the sorted order.

Answer (score 7):

As +Volatility and yourself pointed out, sets are unordered. If you need the elements to be in order, just call `sorted` on the set:

```
>>> y = [1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8]
>>> sorted(set(y))
[1, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 5):

Python's sets (and dictionaries) will iterate and print out in *some* order, but exactly what that order will be is arbitrary, and not guaranteed to remain the same after additions and removals.

Here's an example of a set changing order after a lot of values are added and then removed:

```
>>> s = set([1,6,8])
>>> print(s)
{8, 1, 6}
>>> s.update(range(10,100000))
>>> for v in range(10, 100000):
    s.remove(v)
>>> print(s)
{1, 6, 8}
```

This is implementation dependent though, and so you should not rely upon it.

Answer (score 2):

After reading the other answers, I still had trouble understanding ***why*** the set comes out un-ordered.

Mentioned this to my partner and he came up with this metaphor: take marbles. You put them in a tube a tad wider than marble width : you have a list. A set, however, is a bag. Even though you feed the marbles one-by-one into the bag; when you pour them from a bag back into the tube, they will not be in the same order (because they got all mixed up in a bag).