# Print Only Non Reoccuring Numbers (Python)

Tags: python, printing, numbers, logic

Let me clean this up a bit so people can understand better.

I'm reading into a text file and I'm wanting to print out numbers just once, even if they appear again later on in the list.

Example Text File:

```
 100
 200
 300
 200
```

Based on my logic, since 200 is in the text file twice, I only want to print it once. So my desired output would look like this using the example text file above.

```
 100
 200
 300
```

Here is another example just to clarify (Text file is below)...

```
 250A
 300D
 300D
 300D
 250A
```

The designated output with the example above would be:

```
 250A
 300D
```

Comment: So print `1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4` without `3`?

Comment: Sure, what would work. What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: show all the code required for us to reproduce the problem, and only that code

Comment: Why isn't the output "1, 2, 3, 4" or "1, 2, 2, 4"? If your rule is "print every number that appears, but only once", then 3 should be in the output. If your rule is "print only numbers that don't have a neighbor identical to them", then there should be two 2s in the output.

Comment: I think you have an error in the question, I guess you actually want to print out 1,2,3,4 if that's the real request I would add all numbers to a Set and then print the set.

Comment: Please clarify the question, it is ambiguous as noted by kevin.

Answer (score 2):

If the rule is "print only numbers that don't have a neighbor identical to them":

```
import itertools

def remove_consecutives(seq):
    return [k for k,v in itertools.groupby(seq) if len(list(v)) == 1]

seq = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4]
print remove_consecutives(seq)
#result: [1, 2, 2, 4]
```

If the rule is "print every number that appears, but only once":

```
def remove_repeats(seq):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seen:
            result.append(item)
            seen.add(item)
    return result

seq = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4]
print remove_repeats(seq)
#result: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If the rule is "print every number that appears, but only once, and only if they don't have a neighbor identical to them":

```
import itertools

def remove_consecutives(seq):
    return [k for k,v in itertools.groupby(seq) if len(list(v)) == 1]

def remove_repeats(seq):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seen:
            result.append(item)
            seen.add(item)
    return result

seq = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4]
print remove_repeats(remove_consecutives(seq))
#result: [1, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not read each number from the text file into a set then print the set out?

Comment: that would print every number, eliminating doubles. I think the OP wants to print only those numbers which have no duplicates (in sequence) I may be wrong (see @Kevin's comment above)

Answer (score 0):

You can read those numbers into python list. If they are inside file, it will simply be:

```
with file('your_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers = [line for line in f]
```

Then you can transform that list into set:

```
unique_numbers = set(numbers)
```

And inside `unique_numbers` you will get each number only once.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two people suggested using set() to remove duplicates, which I think is a good idea. Python [sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181867/understanding-the-set-function) are kind of like lists, but each value can only appear once.

Here's some example code:

```
# Import the file as a list
with open('OldFile.txt','r') as f:
    values = f.readlines()

# Make a set object
unique_values = set(values)

# Write the set to a new file
with open('NewFile.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(unique_values)
```

Caution: set() does not respect the order of your elements. If that's a problem, consider [sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sorting_Basics) them like this:

```
unique_values = sorted(set(values))
```