# When making a set out of sorted list, the output set is not sorted

Tags: python, sorting, set

Could anyone please explain to me why making a set out of a sorted list results in a set which is NOT sorted?

**list.sort()** should sort the list in place, as it does. 
**set(list)** should return unique values of the list, as it does.

But why is the resulting set not sorted? Do I need to make a set, turn it back into list2 and then sort list2?

(Using Python 2.7.6)

**Code:**

```
def longest(s1, s2):
    list = []
    s = s1 + s2
    for letter in s:
        list.append(letter)
    print list
    list.sort()
    print list
    unique = set(list)
    print unique
    s4 = ""
    for item in unique:
        s4 = s4 + item
    print s4
    return s4
```

**Console output:**

```
['a', 'r', 'e', 't', 'h', 'e', 'y', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'e', 's', 't', 'h', 'e', 'y', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e']
['a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 's', 't', 't', 'y', 'y', 'y']
set(['a', 'e', 'h', 's', 'r', 't', 'y'])
aehsrty
```

Comment: Set's aren't ordered, so why implement a function that returns them sorted? If you want a sorted set use `sorted(set(x))`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181867/understanding-the-set-function

Comment: sets by definition are unordered

Answer (score 1):

A Python set is by nature unordered. You may use `ordered-set` package if the order matters.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordered-set

Answer (score 1):

Set only ensures it has unique elements and doesn't sort by default.

You need to use sorted(set(list))

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, typing from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Sets are by nature, an unordered data structure. For Python 2.7 the set won't necessarily keep the order but in Python 3.x the order should be kept.