# Does the Python function set() sorts the argument it receives?

Tags: python

Since I tried to apply set function on the integer list, I've just found the set function sometimes returns the set which is sorted, but sometimes not. So I'm wondering does the python function set() sorts the argument it receives.

```py
a=[5,1,4,2,3,7,9,8,6]

print(set(a))

b=[12,65,48,95,71,18,62,33]

print(set(b))

c=[
    85,72,38,80,69,65,68,96,22,49,67,
    51,61,63,87,66,24,80,83,71,60,64,
    52,90,60,49,31,23,99,94,11,25,24
]

print(set(c))
```

This is the code I've used and below are the results I got.

```py
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}

{65, 33, 71, 12, 48, 18, 62, 95}

{11, 22, 23, 24, 25, 31, 38, 49, 51, 52, 60, 61, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 71, 72, 80, 83, 85, 87, 90, 94, 96, 99}
```

You can see the set() function sorted list a and c, but didn't sorted list b. So what is the difference between list a,b,c? Does the set() function really sorts list it received? I'm using Python 3.9.9.

Comment: Sets don't have any defined order.

Comment: No, the output is not sorted. Here is a related question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181867/understanding-the-set-function

Comment: I think it's just an artifact of the way small numbers are hashed that causes the first one to be sorted.